# Merging subsequent cell values only for same ids in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have a requirement here in excel where I have to populate "Facility" column with Country and City names in a single cell for the distributed data in C and D columns but only for the same id.
[image: Attachment for reference]   I have attached the image for reference

Thanks for your time in advance

I tried CONCAT function and TEXTJOIN function but that didn't help

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table31"]}[Content],

//set data types for each column
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"Country", type text}, {"City", type text}}),

//Group by ID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Id"}, {

    //for each subgroup, group by Country
        {"Facility", (t)=> let 
            grp=Table.Group(t,{"Country"},{

    //Then combine all the cities in one text string
              "Cities", (tc)=> "(" & Text.Combine(tc[City],",") & ")"}),

    //Add index column to "number" the different country/cities combinations
            #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(grp, "Index",1),
            #"Index to Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add Index",{"Index", each Number.ToText(_,"0\. ")}),

    //combine the separate subtable columns into one string
            #"Combine Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(
                #"Index to Text",{"Index","Country","Cities"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(""),"Facility"),

    //combine the separate rows into a single row
            #"Combine to One Row" = Text.Combine(#"Combine Columns"[Facility]," ")

        in    
            #"Combine to One Row", type text},
        
        {"All", each _, type table [Id=nullable number, Country=nullable text, City=nullable text]}}),

//Expand the Country and City columns
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Country", "City"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

[image]